# Add class to element when textarea focused

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, focus

I'm trying to add a class to my p element when the textarea is active

This is what I've got so far with no luck.

```
<textarea class="text"></textarea>
  <p class="someClass">
    <span class="span">
      TEXT
    </span>
  </p>
```

jQuery

```
$('textarea').focus(
   $(".someClass").addClass("focused");
});
```

The final result I'm trying to accomplish is when the textarea is focused

```
<textarea class="text"></textarea>
  <p class="someClass focused">
    <span class="span">
      TEXT
    </span>
  </p>
```

Can this be done by grabbing the set class "someClass"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually doing it wrong. You should do this way by sending an anonymous function:

```
$('textarea').focus(function () {
   $(".someClass").addClass("focused");
});
```

You have missed that. I would say a better way, if the `.someClass` is next to the element in question, you can use CSS's sibling selector `+`, without using JavaScript:

```css
textarea:focus + p {
  background: #99f;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<p>Click on TextArea</p>
```

Comment: went with the css method, didnt even think of that.  thank you

Comment: nothing at all... i used 
textarea:focus + p {
  background: #99f;
}

Comment: @DrCustUmz Thanks. Someone downvoted. I don't know why. `:(` Have a nice day buddy.

Answer (score 0):

You should to supply an anonymous function to the `focus` event handler. Try this:

```
$('textarea').focus(function() {
   $(".someClass").addClass("focused");
});
```

Also note that you can do this in CSS alone without the need for any JS code. Using the CSS method has the added benefit of the styles being automatically removed when the `textarea` loses focus.

```
textarea:focus + p {
    /* styles in here which matched the .focused class */
}
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/svv0z7gj/)

Comment: went with the css method, didnt even think of that.  thank you